# Zero average in image processing ( Pascal transformation )

Tags: image, processing, transformation, pascal

I am doing pascal transformation on 4x4 block of image.Anyway i am having some problems at specific placeses.I know how to reduce effect of noice.
1.One point of text i don't understand and that is : Shifting the data values to zero average first will improve this effect.
2.How can i detect all bump in image, every value that's not same as one before is behaving as bump.Maybe some treshhold, but what value should it have ?

Discrete Pascal transformation:
Basicaly it is used to detect bumps and edges.For example when i do transformation on starting matrix z resulting matrix Z will be as :

[matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8Q3t.png)

Comment: Please click `edit` underneath your question and add 4 spaces at the start of each line of your matrices so they align and format correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bump thing alone is very complicated. Basically the simplest is indeed an (absolute) threshold for the difference px[1]-px[0].

(where px[1] is the pixelvalue of pixel n+1, and px[0] is shorthand for the pixelvalue of pixel n)

In certain cases it is better to have a relative check  (px[1]-px[0])/ (0.5*(px[1]+px[0]))>thresrelative AND an absolute check on size  ( abs(px[1]-px[0])>thresh1), the latter to make sure you are not interpreting noise.

That can be further improved by making both px[1] and px[0] some kernel moving average.

These are the basic ones, patterned noised cases have their own tuned cases, or the above checks after some preprocessing (kernel averaging) step.

For more complicated cases, you might also want to look at the Sobel algorithm.